# How to download the file from dropbox using ng-flow of flow.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-flow

I am using ng-flow in my angular.js application to upload the file from desktop to  my server and its working fine and showing like the following image.
[Showing upload process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCPxx.png)

Now i want to upload the file from the dropbox so i am using Dropbox chooser to select the file from dropbox and its giving me the following details.

```
bytes: 457
icon: "https://www.dropbox.com/static/images/icons64/page_white.png"
isDir: false
is_dir: false
link: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/bu98444xdbv0iz04/Example.txt"
name: "Example.txt"
```

Now how can i can i generate the flow object from that information and pass it to ng-flow to see the output like the uper image?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct `flow` object manuall specified all necessary options for it and then call `upload()`. You need to handle right scenario when you are trying to use other resource than local machine

[Here](https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js) you can see full documentation about `Flow.js`

Comment: where i have to pass the url of the file ?

Comment: its a `target` property of your `Flow` object. https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js#how-can-i-use-it

Comment: in target we pass the server method which one is used to save the chunks at specified loaction.like    "target: ''www.example.com/api/upload""  In this "upload" is the server method

Comment: sorry, my mistake. if I understand your case right you can try to create html5 `File` object, then assign it to `Flow.FlowFile.file` property and try do upload

Comment: thanks @Andrew for the reply if you don't mind can you please tell me how to html5 File object from the 
bytes: 457
icon: "https://www.dropbox.com/static/images/icons64/page_white.png"
isDir: false
is_dir: false
link: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/bu98444xdbv0iz04/Example.txt"
name: "Example.txt"

Comment: can you use the link to object instead of bytes?